# How do I read and interpret /proc/acpi/battery/* in a Java program?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to write a java function that gets my battery information from /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/{state info}.
Though I do have a reasonable output as long as my battery isn't plugged in and at full charge I have noticed one problem that happens at full charge and being plugged in.

The remaining capacity in the state file is higher than the last full capacity value found in the info file. 
The two outputs are
/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/info

```
present:                 yes
design capacity:         7800 mAh
last full capacity:      5488 mAh
battery technology:      rechargeable
design voltage:          11100 mV
design capacity warning: 780 mAh
design capacity low:     236 mAh
cycle count:          0
capacity granularity 1:  78 mAh
capacity granularity 2:  78 mAh
model number:            DELL PD6857
serial number:           1857
battery type:            LION
OEM info:                SMP
```

/proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charging
present rate:            2668 mA
remaining capacity:      4422 mAh
present voltage:         12843 mV
```

The problem is that when I'm fully charge my remaining capacity is 7800mAh which is what my design capacity is but when taken off of AC the remaining capacity drops and my presen rate jumps to make the remaining capacity equal to or below my last full capacity.

The question is how to resolve the issue of deciding power.

And based off of the information in those two files how do I create a timer using java to determine how long is left until the battery is full and also how long is left until the battery is empty.

here is my function in the java code.

```
public static int currentCharge(){
    double currentPercent=0;
    int lastFullCapacityInt=0;
    int remainingCapacityInt=0;
    try{
        BufferedReader infoIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(batteryInfo)));
        BufferedReader stateIn=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(batteryState)));
        //first get "last full capacity" from info file.
        String lastFullCapacity="";
        while((lastFullCapacity=infoIn.readLine())!=null){
            if(lastFullCapacity.contains("last full capacity")){
                String[] s=lastFullCapacity.split(":");
                String p=s[1].trim();
                String[] pp=p.split(" ");
                String ppp=pp[0].trim();
                lastFullCapacityInt=Integer.parseInt(ppp);
            }
        }
        infoIn.close();
        //get current capacity from state file
        String remainingCapacity="";
        while((remainingCapacity=stateIn.readLine())!=null){
            if(remainingCapacity.contains("remaining capacity")){
                String[] s=remainingCapacity.split(":");
                String p=s[1].trim();
                String[] pp=p.split(" ");
                String ppp=pp[0].trim();
                remainingCapacityInt=Integer.parseInt(ppp);
            }
        }
        stateIn.close();

    } catch(Exception e){
    }
    currentPercent=(((double)remainingCapacityInt/lastFullCapacityInt)*100);
    int c=(int)currentPercent;
    double d=(currentPercent-c)*100;
    if(((int)d)>50)
            c+=1;
    System.out.println(currentPercent);
    return (c);
}
```

Just wanted to add the /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0/state file when my battery is fully charged so everyone can see what I am talking about.

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          charged
present rate:            1 mA
remaining capacity:      7800 mAh
present voltage:         13010 mV
```

the next reading is approximately 20 seconds after being taken off of AC power

```
present:                 yes
capacity state:          ok
charging state:          discharging
present rate:            1993 mA
remaining capacity:      5456 mAh
present voltage:         12650 mV
```

Comment: You might want to consider the Properties class to parse out the value pairs. It would make your code quite a bit more readable.

Comment: Does the Properties class sort them out into key/value pairs?? I'll look it up, thank you.

Comment: what is the value of batteryInfo and batterystate?can u show some code?as i m getting NAN for BufferedReader and it goes into exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misreading the contents of the info file. `present rate` and `remaining capacity` are not measured in the same units -- the former is a discharge rate in milliamps, while the latter is a capacity in milliamp-hours. (If we take current to be distance, these are equivalent to miles-per-hour and miles.)

As such, you can get the predicted "time to empty", given a discharge rate and a remaining capacity, by dividing the capacity by the rate; since the two values are measured in milliamp-hours and milliamps, the result is in hours. Using your last info file as a sample, for instance:

```
capacity  = 5456 (mAh)
rate      = 1993 (mA)
time left = 5456 / 1993 = 2.73 (hours)
```

As to why the remaining capacity drops abruptly when you unplug the machine, chances are that you just have a bad battery, or your machine's battery measurement isn't particularly accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the time remaining info.

Should I continue to use last full capacity for measurement and just limit the output to 100%?

When the battery is fully charged and plugged in my current power percent reads out at 142% which is highly innacurate XD

example from my test of this method is:

142.12827988338194
142%

Comment: As far as that goes, you should probably be using the `design capacity` of the battery, not the `last full capacity`. The latter might simply be wrong if your battery is sometimes charged partway.

Comment: I know it has been a couple of years but I thought I would add some information I've learned over the last couple of years to this question.
As I understand it now
The design capacity is what the battery was designed to hold and the last full capacity was the last time the battery was completely charged according to the chips on the battery.
you can get the information on how much a battery has degraded by doing
last full capacity / design capacity = current percentage(health of the battery)
I could be wrong